# Get ImportError after installing EttusResearch UHD with Conda

Tags: python, conda, uhd, conda-forge

I installed UHD with Conda using the `conda install -c conda-forge uhd` command. Then I ran `conda install uhd`. When I try to import `uhd` in `Python3.6`, I get an `ImportError`:

```
>>> import uhd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/asamant/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uhd/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import types
  File "/home/asamant/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uhd/types.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import libpyuhd as lib
ImportError: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependency on `libudev` cannot be shipped via conda-forge and therefore you yourself have to make sure it is available.

You need to install a`libudev-0.x` package manually (`libudev1` won't work!)

<del>The easiest way to solve this is to use your system's package manager, e.g. `apt-get install libudev1` for Ubuntu.</del>

It looks to me as if `libudev.so.0` is different from `libudev.so.1` shipped via the libudev1 package by the ubuntu package manager.

There seem to be ways around, but it is not a beautiful solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/729067/libudev0-is-not-installed